# Какой лучший JS слайдер для галереи фото?

Tags: javascript, slider

Нужно сделать галерею фотографий, через слайдер(обычный скролл не вариант). И первое что мне пришло в голову `Slick.js`, но я понял что это не вариант, тк использую чистый js и не хочу перегружать сайт тяжелым jQuery. Так вот, какой есть также удобный слайдер как slick но без jQuery? Могу рассмотреть варианты. Галерея должна менять размер сетки в зависимости от размера экрана

Comment: swiperjs подойдет?

Comment: если не к спеху, можете сами написать галерею. При этом будет только что вам нужно

Comment: @Ceri неплохой вариант, по демкам мне нравится. Добавьте это предложение в ответ. Пока дам +1, а когда встрою это в свой сайт, и мне оно подойдет, отмечу ответом :)

Comment: @RavshanSelimov мог бы, да вот опыта мало в js :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько вариантов с первой страницы гугла и коротким описанием.

[SwiperJs](https://swiperjs.com/) - Превосходный слайдер, заточен для работы с мобильными версиями сайта и веб-приложениями. Swiper обеспечивает аппаратное ускорение анимации на нативном уровне. Гибкий, имеет множество настроек. Подогнать можно под любой дизайн или задачу.

[Owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) - Плагин для создания слайдеров. Имеет интуитивные настройки точек остановки слайдера. Адаптивен. Отлично работает как на мобильной, так и на десктопной версии.

[Glidejs](https://glidejs.com/) – Независимый от JavaScript слайдер/карусель на ES6. Легкий, гибкий и быстрый. Предназначен для скольжения. Не меньше, не больше.

Comment: За что вас заминусили? Ответ же, такой, как я просил? Да и вопрос кто-то минусанул

Comment: @DarkRou Без понятия, может что-то не понравилось, может погода за окном плохая.